# Edits by same user merged in edit history

Tags: discussion, edits, privacy

So I edited and flagged a privacy issue yesterday (question by a new user), and got this back as the flag comment:

> OP had real name listed in error trace. I removed but should probably remove from edit history for privacy. – Daniel F 16 hours ago   helpful - Thanks. Another time, please perform the edit which redacts information separately from other changes. Doing so makes it easier to match the change you made

Thing is, I'm pretty sure I actually did that, expecting that it would make the admin's job easier - removed the name, flagged, and then edited again to fix the rest.  But apparently it all got mashed together since I was the only editor.  Is there a timeout that I should wait for so that successive edits don't get merged, or just not bother doing further edits in these special cases?

Comment: Your second edit may have occurred in the [grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251876): "Edits will be rolled into the previous revision if the previous revision was created by the same author and *none* of the following conditions are present: The previous revision was created 5 minutes or more in the past" ...

Comment: OK, so 5 minutes.  I didn't see that one, thanks.

Comment: The canonical is *[How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788)* (cross site). The section *"Grace period"* lists the exceptions to the 5 minute "rule" (for instance, a new comment will shorten the 5 minute grace period).